# Getting exception of Invalid length in decryption from AES Algorithm

Tags: c#, android, encryption, aes

I am getting exception of invalid length in time of decryption in AES algorithm in C#, while it's working fine in android code.

Android Code:

```
     public byte[] decryp_decompress(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
                  throws Exception {
           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
           GZip gzip = new GZip();
           byte[] decompressData = gzip.decompresses(decrypted);

           return decompressData;
    }
```

C# Code:

```
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        try
        {
            return rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And

```
    public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] AESKey = new byte[] { **** };
            var keyBytes = new byte[16];
            var secretKeyBytes = AESKey;
            Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
            return new RijndaelManaged
            {
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                Padding = PaddingMode.None,
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Key = keyBytes
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Getting exception in time of decryption of invalid length.

What could the issue be?

Edit:

I have made changes for decryption:

```
  KeyParameter par = new KeyParameter(AESKey);
  // SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
   IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.Init(true, par);
        // Gives me "pad block corrupted" error
        byte[] output = new byte[(encryptedData.Length)];
        int len = cipher.ProcessBytes(encryptedData, 0,    encryptedData.Length, output, 0);
        cipher.DoFinal(output, encryptedData.Length);
        // byte[] output = cipher.DoFinal(encryptedData);
        return output;
```

but getting exception of  data not block size aligned.

My data saved in little endian format . so any please help me where i need to update the code.

Comment: Good formatting is your friend. Use it. What is the full exception message exactly and on which line?

Comment: Getting exception in this line "rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);" of Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: Seems like I missed something. Soner Gönül

Comment: Why are you catching exceptions just to re-throw the exact same exceptions?

Comment: If you are getting "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid", then check that the length of the `encryptedData` array is a multiple of the block size and it as big as you expect it to be (including padding).

Comment: @rossum How can I identify the length ??

Comment: It is an array, so use `encryptedData.length`.

Comment: Each data have different size of length. So how it will identify.

Comment: Check if `encryptedData` in C# is exactly identical to the ciphertext `encrypted` for Android by printing both out as hexadecimal string.